# CountIf - How to escape special characters (angle brackets)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of times a specific cell value occurs within an Excel spreadsheet, using VBA. The cell value is an XML tag, and the angle brackets are interpreted by the function as less than/more than. How can these characters be escaped?

Microsoft says:

"You can use the wildcard characters, question mark (?) and asterisk (*), for the criteria. A question mark matches any single character; an asterisk matches any sequence of characters. **If you want to find an actual question mark or asterisk, type a tilde (~) before the character.**"

But this does not seem to work for me. My code:

```
count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), "<element>")
```

Comment: I don't seem to have a problem counting the `<element>` without the need of `~`.  are you sure there are no other characters like spaces in the cells that are trying to be counted that may be throwing of the search?

Comment: Does `<element>` appear by itself in cells, or is it part of other text?

Comment: `<element>` does appear by itself and without spaces, and when I use ctrl+f in Excel I get the right number of results counted. DGulledge's solution fixed my problems though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should push the bracket to be read as part of the string since the equals sign is read as the evaluation.

```
count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), "=<element>")
```